# What is the difference between clicking the refresh button in the browser and selecting the link and pressing enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my web application,I have made a pin popup which is supposed to popup and disable the rest of the screen after a timeout. When the page is refreshed(Ctrl+R) or clicking on the refresh button, the pin popup appears, but if the link is highlighted and enter key is pressed, the popup does not come.
How is the (click on link and press enter) different from a (Ctrl+R) or clicking on the refresh button?
Please Help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this a single page application? like angularjs or reactjs?

Comment: How/When do you show the popup?  After a form POST?

Comment: I really like you to explain the problem in a bit more depth. But looking at your heading! Refreshing a pagae and selecting the link are really 2 different thinks! when you refresh a page you are sending a new request to the browser requesting for the same page! whereas clicking a link you are requesting whatever the link's href is pointing to !

Comment: This is a three page application. I want to show the pin popup after 10 minutes of inactivity by the user. The pin popup should take a four digit password and then open the application. If the user refreshes the page, the pin popup should reappear. If the user refreshes by using (Ctrl+R) or clicks on the refresh button, the pop up appears, but if he selects the link in the browser and presses enter, the popup does not reappear. What is happening is unclear to me.

Comment: To whomever voted close because "questions asking why isn't this code working? .. must include code" - this question is not a "why isn't this code working" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Generally:* clicking on a link (or tab to and enter/space) starts a new GET (get from scratch (like open a new browser and paste the url in the address)).

While refresh/ctrl-r *resends* the previous command - if this was a POST then you get another POST.

You can use ctrl-f5 for a new GET.

---

In addition: Any element on a page (specifically a link in this case) may have an `event handler` applied which can stop the default action.

So, if yout link has an event handler that contains `e.preventDefault();` or `return false;`  (eg `<a href='...' onclick='return false;'>link</a>`) then it would appear that nothing is happening.

Pressing enter/space on a focused link is the same as clicking it (runs the `.click()` event handler).

Answer (score 0):

Clicking Refresh or Ctr+R reloads page by making a fresh server request. In this case, making a server request is done for sure which is not the case when you just click & enter the link in address bar. In 2nd scenario, it just reloads the page. It mayor may not go to server but reloads it from browser cache.